# EF Core - AutoInc field based on tenant

Tags: c#, entity-framework

how I can create an identity field in a table that is augmented base on another field? 
Here a simple example of what I need

```
TENANT  ID
1       1
1       2
1       3
1       4
2       1
2       2
2       3
3       1
3       2
3       3
```

Basically I'm able to write a code for do this, but I don't want the responsability of concurrency management :)
There's a function of ef core to do this?

Comment: Why? The value of `ID` shouldn't matter. Just use a regular identity column.

Comment: because I need an autoincremente valued per tenant, such as order number and I don't want missing number in the same tenant

Comment: @DavideMartelli What you are wanting is not possible. But close solution is make them composite key and set the value manually.

Comment: Since this is not possible "by default" in DBMS (mysql "sort of" supports it), EF does not support this. Either you'll have to create the values yourself (like @TanvirArjel suggested) or use a trigger and trick EF by using a shadow key.

Comment: *I don't want missing number in the same tenant* -- Again: why? The ID values should be meaningless to the application logic.

Comment: @GertArnold because is the customers request.

Comment: thanks to all for the explanataion